# In prestashop multistore how to show different content for different shops by editing the common mdoule files

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I have enable multistore in prestashop and have created two shops for example http://sample.com and http://sample.com/shop1. But i have a single common modules folder for both shops. If i need to change the particular line of code, we have written in a module.tpl file and make it to dispaly as "welcome to our shop" text in first http://sample.com and "Have a great" text in http://sample.com/shop1. How to achieve this one? Is it possible with jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this from your php file. and send the gretting message to tpl file like

```
$id_shop = $this->context->shop->id;
```

by depending on your shop id you can send message to your tpl file , then you can show the message by jquery.

Comment: can you explain it briefly.In which php file we need to add the code? @arifur rahman

Comment: If you are using any module, in that case you can add that on your module file . If you are doing mymodule , in that case you can insert the code in your hookclass before assign template file. are you trying in your module or any other file to achieve this.